# Which synonym for seedcalendar is used most?

Tags: planting, food-crops, sowing

There are different synonyms you can use when you are talking about a calendar of sow information. To my knowledge these are the ones:

1.sow calendar
2. planting calendar
3. seed calendar
4. crop calendar.

Now suppose i want to make a website about a seedcalendar. Which term should i use best as a domain name?

thank you

Comment: "sow information" is about pig farming, not gardening ;) But seriously, in the UK the only term I would expect is "planting calendar". "Crop calendar" might include planting times but it would also be about harvesting times, IMO.

Comment: how about grow calendar and gardening calendar?